# Python - Selenium - Cannot Find Element on Page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using Selenium for a while now and am trying to extract LinkedIn company ID's from their LinkedIn company page. Every tag in this section is dynamic or not unique. So I went for xpath.

```html
<code style="display: none" id="bpr-guid-3744658">
  {"data":{"elements":["Ts9RZEZq7awx/7fUFM1C+A==,0"],"paging":{"count":10,"start":0,"links":[]}},"included":[{"$deletedFields":[],"width":800,"fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment":"800_800/0?e=1536192000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=6ny2TVRT-FUOSV45OcAvzB5KWQlEJM0YmuPxexVNx0M","height":800,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.VectorArtifact","$id":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-3"},{"$deletedFields":[],"width":400,"fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment":"400_400/0?e=1536192000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=-5gPpNm7Ro7cttZe-oKhpFK0cwbm11VMH9uHoptg1Mk","height":400,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.VectorArtifact","$id":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-2"},{"$deletedFields":[],"width":200,"fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment":"200_200/0?e=1536192000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=4xw5nz_6JCFJpMCvqp3zYgpWu4vkjT88sgc7mmZBMiM","height":200,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.VectorArtifact","$id":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-1"},{"$deletedFields":[],"width":100,"fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment":"100_100/0?e=1536192000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=FrXLV0ITY8qMu6Qm-C6domrXpRbUWbbhWCZpeWffJfI","height":100,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.VectorArtifact","$id":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-0"},{"$deletedFields":["attribution"],"artifacts":["urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-0","urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-1","urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-2","urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage,artifacts,80a83d1c-6000-4576-ac86-2403150cd7ab-3"],"rootUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHWo0jcnWXI7A/profile-displayphoto-shrink_","$type":"com.linkedin.common.VectorImage","$id":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage"},{"profilePicture":{"com.linkedin.common.VectorImage":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo,profilePicture,com.linkedin.common.VectorImage"},"firstName":"Stephanie","lastName":"Goldberger","$deletedFields":[],"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.identity.normalizedprofile.Profile"},{"inNetworkPeopleSearchUrl":"https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_N=F&amp;f_CC=1288","$deletedFields":[],"totalNumberOfConnections":1,"topConnectionsResolutionResults":{"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo":"urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo"},"topConnections":["urn:li:fs_normalized_profile:ACoAAAI8JnMBdj5agxf-k-p3EhA5XpUNvhknDIo"],"$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.jobs.shared.InNetworkRelevanceReasonDetails","$id":"Ts9RZEZq7awx/7fUFM1C+A==,0,details,com.linkedin.voyager.jobs.shared.InNetworkRelevanceReasonDetails"},{"$deletedFields":[],"company":"urn:li:fs_normalized_company:1288","details":{"com.linkedin.voyager.jobs.shared.InNetworkRelevanceReasonDetails":"Ts9RZEZq7awx/7fUFM1C+A==,0,details,com.linkedin.voyager.jobs.shared.InNetworkRelevanceReasonDetails"},"$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.organization.relevance.CompanyRelevanceReason","$id":"Ts9RZEZq7awx/7fUFM1C+A==,0"}]}
</code>
```

In the inspect dev tools, this command returns the expected results:

```
e = $x('//*[contains(.,"bpr-guid-3744658")]')
```

However, because the id is dynamic, I tried this instead:

```
e = $x('//*[contains(.,"bpr-guid-")]')
```

This returns results, but the right node is not in the list. The node after the one I am looking for actually made it into the list.

My program is in Python, but I am using JavaScript as it is much faster to debug (so solutions in Python instead are much appreciated).

[Datalet is in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zesyP.png)

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `starts_with` instead of contains, I would also recommend using `id` instead of `.`, like this:

```
 CompanyList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//code[starts-with(@id, "bpr-guid")]')
```

If the elements do not always have tag `<code` or they do not `start-with @id` = ***bpr-guid***, then we can come up with another more direct solution than what you were trying before to narrow down the list of *elements*.

Answer (score 0):

`//*[starts-with(@id, "bpr-guid")]`